# Typecasting a numerical value entered by a user through prompt

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 5 items. I want the user to choose one item.

```
devops_tutorials = ["Git","Jenkins","Docker","Ansible","Vagrant"];
```

I want the user to choose one of the options from values 1 through 5

```
var user_option = prompt("Which Course? 1.Git | 2.Jenkins | 3.Docker | 4.Ansible | 5.Vagrant");
```

Now, the typeof user_option is showing as a string. So, 
On the console when I'm printing the value chosen by the user, should I convert the variable user_option to number? But without typecasting, I dont understand why the below statement is working fine.

```
console.log("you have chosen" + devops_tutorials[user_option-1]);
```

And this is also working fine

```
console.log("You have chosen" +devops_tutorials[Number(user_option)-1]);
```

I expect javascript to throw an error when I'm passing the variable without typecasting. What's happening internally?

Answer (score 2):

The `-` operator can only be used on numbers, so when the interpreter encounters something that *isn't* a number on the right or left side of a `-`, it will try to convert it to a number. For example:

```js
const obj = {
  valueOf() {
    return 5;
  }
};

console.log(obj - 3);
```

In your case, since `prompt` returns a string, if the string is numerical, it'll be easily converted to a value of `number` type automatically. No explicit type casting is necessary.

Using the `-` operator on something that can't be sensibly converted to a number will almost never actually throw an error - at worst, it'll usually just result in `NaN`:

```js
const obj = {};

console.log(obj - 3);
```

Typescript, on the other hand, generally *does* require explicit type casting.

Answer (score 2):

What is probably THE main problem of Javascript is that it does all kinds of casting automatically.

While this sometimes does save some keyboard wearing, often it becomes a nightmare when debugging.

In your case you should understand that `"3" - 1` in Javascript gives `2`, and that `"3" + 1` instead gives `"31"`.

Welcome to hell